# Where can I see my Drivatar's behavior?

Tags: forza-motorsport-5

in Forza 5, your "drivatar" learns from your playstyle and goes against other players during their races. My question is is there anywhere I can see how my drivatar actually drives? I did manage to find a screen that has a bunch of statistics, but nothing along the lines of "your Drivatar is very aggressive" or something like that.

my playstyle changes with each car and track (GT-R is much more grippy than a Viper, so I can be more aggressive with it) so I'd like to see how the Drivatar reacts to that.

Comment: From what I've heard, almost everyone's Drivatar drives like a maniac, regardless of their actual driving habits in-game. :P

Comment: No, I have come across Opponent Drivatars that are exceptional at blocking/drafting/passing, while others make it a habit to slide out of corners at full throttle in a VW Beetle... and then theres the maniac drivatars you mention that think their Lambo is an offroad rally car...

Comment: One thing I noticed is when you complete a multiplayer race, the Xbox takes over you car and continues driving until the race is finished. Now, I really don't hope that's how my drivatar drives but it could give an idication of how it does...

Answer (score 1):

I got this from http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/drivatar/forza.aspx

***Once you have completed at least one Drivatar lesson, entering "Observe" mode allows you to watch your Drivatar drive on any of the five tracks where the lessons have been completed.*** This allows you to assess you Drivatar's performance and perhaps see how your own driving might be improved to take advantage of any traits you observe in your Drivatar. Once you have completed all the lessons and your Drivatar is mature you will be able to watch it drive at any circuit in the game (another cunning back door – this time to checking out the locked tracks in the game) in any car in your garage. This is where you can start to appreciate the technology behind the Drivatar. The Drivatar is not a simple recording of your driving specific to the track and car combination from the lessons. Instead, your Drivatar infers a probabilistic model of your "style" of driving in general by monitoring your line with respect to the geometry of the track, and your speed with respect to the capabilities of your car.
Think about it ... you have trained your Drivatar to drive on 5 different tracks in 5 particular cars and now it is able to drive all the tracks in the game in all cars – though effectively it has never experienced them before. If you think that is simple, think again! What has just happened is that you have trained a computer how to drive any track in the game just by driving 3 laps of 5 tracks. In "machine learning" terms that is almost miraculous! In order to train a computer how to do the most menial of real world tasks we typically have to provide hundreds of thousands of examples of data.

However i'm unable to find anything about how to enter observation mode. I guess you have to make sure you complete a full lesson then see if you can find a observe mode.

Comment: Sounds like Forza Motorsport 2.